# What solution to amend a Pull Request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have made a PR on GitHub (Enterprise) with few commits. My reviewers identified a small mistake on one commit:

```
* a401341c Did this (HEAD -> foo)
* 08e97f86 Did that
* 616cd4ad Done that
* f3c6151b Accomplished this
* 1af6e74f Fix this <-- Error there
* a099fc19 Finished this
* ab726eb3 Cherry-picked this (master, origin/master)
```

The first solution is to revert all commits after `1af6e74f` because I cannot just revert it without conflicts, then reapply all the commits with the correction:

```
* 0c99cf29 Reapply Did this (HEAD -> foo)
* 8806f36b Reapply Did that
* 572e1122 Reapply Done that
* 64ea3dc8 Reapply Accomplished this
* 81e20976 Fix this (this time correctly)
* d78a4534 Revert Fix this <-- Error there
* c0d817a9 Revert Accomplished this
* ed2bb3b2 Revert Done that
* ea34322a Revert Did that
* f81b78a3 Revert Did this
* a401341c Did this
* 08e97f86 Did that
* 616cd4ad Done that
* f3c6151b Accomplished this
* 1af6e74f Fix this <-- Error there
* a099fc19 Finished this
* ab726eb3 Cherry-picked this (master, origin/master)
```

Then `git push` to update my PR.

The second solution would involve a `git push -f`

```
git checkout 1af6e74f 
git commit --amend -am "Fix this (with corrections)"
git rebase --onto a401341c f3c6151b HEAD # Not sure this will work as written
git branch -f foo HEAD
git push -f
```

Is the former solution a good solution and the latter always a bad one?

Comment: I wouldn't use either, I would just fix the boo boo in a new commit.  Of course, the history would be cleaner if you rebased the branch.  But rebasing would only be advisable if your branch were not shared by anyone else.  So the answer to your question is that the latter solution is a good one if the branch is not shared.

Comment: Well, I can't... It wasn't made clear in my question tough because I used `git am mypatch` where I cannot just apply a patch. I need to revert and alter a specific commit. It is like I do `s/a\w/b/g` on one commit, I cannot really just do `s/b/a/g` afterwards.

Comment: If you can't rebase, then why did you ask about it, or was this question just hypothetical?

Comment: I can actually rebase but not the way I presented there... (I'll modify the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question* :

What is the diff between your old branch and the new branch (git diff a401341c 0c99cf29) ?
Does it look like a reasonable patch, which indicates clearly enough how the bug was fixed ?

---

If it does, just take the new content and commit this as a new commit on top of your old branch :

```
git checkout foo

# just to be on the safe side : work on a new temporary branch
git checkout -b wip

# go back to the old sate :
git reset --hard a401341c   # <- original "Did this" commit

# get the content from new branch :
git checkout 0c99cf29 .   # <- don't forget the "."

# check that it matches what you expect :
git diff [--cached] ...
git difftool -d [--cached] ...

# if OK : commit !
git commit


# make your local "foo" branch point to this commit :
git checkout foo
git reset --hard wip
git branch -d wip

# push :
git push origin foo
```

Comment: In this case I have to do `git push -f origin foo` which is normally not allowed. Right ?

Comment: It will be a regumar push, not a `git push -f`. Your changes will be committed on top of the remote branch.